# Custom React Hook Not Working With Rollup

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, react-hooks, rollup

I've created a Typescript React component library and using Rollup to bundle and then publish to npm. Now everything works great in storybook but when I pull the package into another project it just doesn't work. No errors, nothing just the hook doesn't fire.

Here is my rollup.config.js

```
import commonjs from "@rollup/plugin-commonjs";
import copy from "rollup-plugin-copy";
import peerDepsExternal from "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external";
import postcss from "rollup-plugin-postcss";
import resolve from "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve";
import typescript from "rollup-plugin-typescript2";

const packageJson = require("./package.json");

export default {
  input: "src/index.ts",
  output: [
    {
      file: packageJson.main,
      format: "cjs",
      sourcemap: true
    },
    {
      file: packageJson.module,
      format: "esm",
      sourcemap: true
    }
  ],
  external: ['react', 'react-dom'],
  plugins: [
    peerDepsExternal(),
    resolve(),
    commonjs(),
    typescript({ useTsconfigDeclarationDir: true }),
    postcss(),
    copy({
      targets: [
        {
          src: "src/styles/variables.scss",
          dest: "build",
          rename: "variables.scss"
        },
        {
          src: "src/styles/typography.scss",
          dest: "build",
          rename: "typography.scss"
        }
      ]
    })
  ]
};
```

and here is my hook useResize:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

import styles from '../styles/variables.scss';

export const useResize = (ref) => {
  const [size, updateSize] = useState({});
  const [sizeIndex, updatesizeIndex] = useState(null);

  const xsMax = parseInt(styles.xsMax)
  const smMax = parseInt(styles.smMax)
  const mdMax = parseInt(styles.mdMax)
  const lgMax = parseInt(styles.lgMax)
  const xlMax = parseInt(styles.xlMax)

  const getDimensions = () => ({
    width: ref.current.offsetWidth,
    height: ref.current.offsetHeight
  });

  const setSize = () => {
    let dimensions = getDimensions();
    if (dimensions.width > xlMax) {
      updateSize('xxl');
      updatesizeIndex(5);
    }
    if ((dimensions.width <= xlMax) && (dimensions.width > lgMax)) {
      updateSize('xl');
      updatesizeIndex(4);
    }
    if ((dimensions.width <= lgMax) && (dimensions.width > mdMax)) {
      updateSize('lg');
      updatesizeIndex(3);
    }
    if ((dimensions.width <= mdMax) && (dimensions.width > smMax)) {
      updateSize('md');
      updatesizeIndex(2);
    }
    if ((dimensions.width <= smMax) && (dimensions.width > xsMax)) {
      updateSize('sm');
      updatesizeIndex(1);
    }
    if (dimensions.width <= xsMax) {
      updateSize('xs');
      updatesizeIndex(0);
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleResize = () => {
      setSize();
    }
    if (ref.current) {
      setSize();
    }
    window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize)
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize)
    }
  }, [ref])

  return [size, sizeIndex]
}
```

And here is how its used:

```
import "./Row.scss";

import React, { FC, useCallback, useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

import { RowProps } from "./Row.types";
import _ from 'lodash';
import clsx from "clsx";
import { useResize } from "./useResize";

const Row: FC<RowProps> = ({ gutter, columns, children, title, subTitle }: RowProps) => {
    const rowRef = useRef(null);
    const [columnsRef, updateColumnsRef] = useState(columns);
    const [size, sizeIndex] = useResize(rowRef);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (_.isNumber(columns))
            return;
        !columns[sizeIndex] ?
            updateColumnsRef(_.last(columns)) :
            updateColumnsRef(columns[sizeIndex]);
        console.log(size)
    }, [size, sizeIndex]);

    const renderStyles = useCallback(() => {
        return {
            display: 'grid',
            gridTemplateColumns: `repeat(${columnsRef}, minmax(0, 1fr))`,
            gridGap: gutter,
        }
    }, [columnsRef])

    return <div className={clsx("Row")} ref={rowRef}>
        {title &&
            <div className="Row-heading">
                <h4>{title}</h4>
                <h5>{subTitle}</h5>
            </div>
        }
        <div className="Row-container" style={renderStyles()}>
            {children}
        </div>
    </div>
};

Row.defaultProps = {
    columns: 12,
    gutter: 24
}

export default Row;
```

Comment: So looks like the issue is with pulling the in the sass variables. Rollup doesn't read them so nothing works. Hardcoded the values and it worked, but I still want a way to use sass variables in the hook